# php array value repeated for each key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array made from database query and is like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => -8.63296022565696
            [x] => -8.63296022565696
            [1] => 41.1584289069069
            [y] => 41.1584289069069
            [2] => 0
            [seq] => 0
            [3] => 2
            [seq2] => 2
            [4] => -8.63306031211831
            [next_x] => -8.63306031211831
            [5] => 41.1584543235506
            [next_y] => 41.1584543235506
            [6] => -8.64195115878864
            [alert_x] => -8.64195115878864
            [7] => 41.1599295066425
            [alert_y] => 41.1599295066425
            [8] => 54e728edafac1
            [route] => 54e728edafac1
            [9] => 54e728edafac1
            [routeid] => 54e728edafac1
            [10] => 2
            [counttargetinter] => 2
            [11] => passeio
            [type] => passeio
            [12] => 1355
            [arcid] => 1355
        )
```

All the values are repeated because have a key number and a key name.
 Example: The value `'-8.63296022565696'` are in key `"0"` and `"X"`.

How I can remove the duplicated?

This is how i made the array:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM foo;";
$startRows =  pg_query($connection, $query);
$startInfo = array();   
while($list = pg_fetch_array($startRows)) {
    $startInfo[] = $list;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am searching for a way of deleting all values with integer keys.

Comment: According to me its JSON

Comment: The array_unique is not want i want because its possible that my array have correct not unique values . Example two points with same latitude.

Comment: yes, its JSON because i made json_encode. I will correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Ghost:

You can use [pg_fetch_row()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-row.php) to get numeric indices or [pg_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php) to get field name.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM foo;";
$startRows =  pg_query($connection, $query);
$startInfo = array();   
while($list = pg_fetch_row($startRows)) {
    $startInfo[] = $list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can't mess with the generate JSON string to deal with the dups. You solve it during the creation of the array itself before encoding. Looking at the structure, this seems to be the problem of fetching both numeric and column indices.

Since you haven't posted any codes related to actually creating this JSON string, just use this basic idea on how to get rid of them.

If you intent do remove those numeric indices, you'll probably need to use `fetch_assoc()` flavours of your database API, so that in turn, you'll only get the column name indices instead of having them both.

Here's the idea:

```
$data = array(); // initialization of the container
while($row = your_fetch_assoc($result)) { // use assoc() instead to exclude those numeric indices
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Depending on what API you're using, if its `PDO`, either use `-->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` or just `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` without the need of a loop. If its `MySQLi`, then just use `->fetch_assoc()`

EDIT: At last your codes, as I have suspected you're using `_array()` function which results associative and numeric indexed rows.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM foo;";
$startRows =  pg_query($connection, $query);
$startInfo = array();   
while($list = pg_fetch_assoc($startRows)) {
    $startInfo[] = $list;
}
```

Use [pg_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php) instead of `_array()` so that you'll get the associative indices only.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question. You can see how i do the array

Comment: @pdcc yeah, my suspicion is correct, you're using `_array()`, use `_assoc()` instead, check my revised answer above.

Comment: @Ghost You almost guessed right with `*_assoc()` only the `pg_*` you didn't guessed :D

Comment: @Rizier123 yeah, i was blind with regards to that, i was guessing either PDO or MySQLi, and both failed. lol :D

Comment: @pdcc sure, glad this shed some light

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($walkroute as $routepoints){
    foreach($routepoints as $key => $value){
       if (is_int($key)){
         unset($routepoints[$key]);
       }
    }
}
```

You have to modify it due to the fact that i don't know, what the structure and names of your array actually are.